# I Can't decrypt file after reinstalling windows?

Tags: windows, encryption, cmd

I have problem with microsoft encrypt content to secure data.
I had encrypt file 2 year ago, but now I reinstall windows, but I forget about decryption file before install. How can I decrypt those file ?

Sincerely you
Suchai

Answer (score 0):

if you have the key (.pfx) file you can do it.
you must have EFS Certificate for user that crypt files.
That is the point if you dont have key or certificate you cant get them back.

Comment: T_T i think i don't have .PFX File did you have another way to get data back please.

Comment: i tried to get my .pfx from third part app which can get some document after format but there were no .pfx file if i can find a way, let you know.